# Accessing custom properties, python

Tags: python, properties, custom-properties

In my addon I'm declaring an enum that is storing 3 properties.

I tried to read up on how to pass properties between files, but I can't figure this one out.

I would like to access the properties from another file, but getting the error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'scene'"

In one file I'm declaring the property:

```
import bpy

class Expression(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    expression_type: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="Expressions", description="expressions to choose from",
        items=[('OP1', "A*B if A>0 and B>0", ""),
               ('OP2', "(A*B)**0.5", ""),
               ('OP3', "sin(pi/2*A)*sin(pi/2*B)", "")],
        default='OP1'
    )
      
def register():
    register_class(Expression)
    bpy.types.Object.expression_type = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="Expressions", description= "expressions to choose from",
        items= [('OP1', "A*B if A>0 and B>0", ""),
                ('OP2', "(A*B)**0.5", ""),
                ('OP3', "sin(pi/2*A)*sin(pi/2*B)", "")],
        default='OP1'
    )

def unregister():
    unregister_class(Expression)
    del bpy.types.Object.expression_type
```

and in the other I'm trying to access it:

```
class ShapeUpdate:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def update_shapes(self, context, selected_meshes, active_mesh):
        scene = context.object

        if scene.expression_type == 'OP1':
            print('do thing A')
        elif scene.expression_type == 'OP2':
            print('do thing B')
        elif scene.expression_type == 'OP3':
            print('do thing C')
            
class ShapeEditor_OT_UpdateShape(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Updates the shapekey and connects drivers according to naming conventions"""
    bl_idname = "shapeeditor.updateshape"
    bl_label = "Update Shape"
    bl_description = "Update shape keys based on naming convention, to get drivers and act as either " \
                     "combination or inbetween"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.active_object is not None)

    def __init__(self):
        self.selected_meshes = self.meshselect.get_selected_meshes()
        self.active_mesh = self.meshselect.get_active_mesh()

    def execute(self, context):
        self.update = ShapeUpdate()
        self.update.update_shapes('INVOKE_DEFAULT', self.selected_meshes, self.active_mesh)

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

I'm probably overlooking something. Pretty hard to find some information on the subject. I tried to look at other peoples addon but didn't have much luck.

Comment: Hello ! It seems you didn't provide the full script, there is no mention of `scene` in the snippet you posted so the error doesn't come from there

Comment: Thank you for replying. I updated the second snippet with the original variable declaration. 

The script works fine until I put in the conditional statements trying to access that property so I'm positive it has to do something with how/where I'm declaring that custom property or how I'm trying to access it.

Comment: You should look into your function arguments, you call `update_shapes` with a string as first argument when the signature expects a `context`. Try replacing `'INVOKE_DEFAULT'` with `context`

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Trying to understand blender and it's contexts but it's not an easy process.